# SKStoreProductViewController showing iPad store view inside of iPhone app (when running on iPad)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, storekit

We're currently developing an app that is targeted to the iPhone (i.e. doesn't yet have any native iPad UI and is NOT Universal).  One of the big features in iOS 6 is the ability to run the iTunes stores inside the app via the SKStoreProductViewController.  However, when running our app on the iPad, the iPad is still showing the **iPad** store, instead of the **iPhone** store.  This creates a bunch of usability issues, as the larger iPad store assumes that it has a much larger area to display it's content that it actually has (off screen buttons, lists that scroll in 20px height, etc).

Is there a flag or any way we can work around this behavior? We are eventually planning on a native iPad UI, but our client would like to demo/release the iPhone app for the first phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can't config the `SKStoreProductViewController` UI by now. The SDK didn't supply any custom settings, although we all need it.